# Postgresql: Difference between pg_dump and backup/restore?

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore

Don't they essentially do the same thing by storing all the data in a file and dumping it into another database? Is it that `pg_dump` just adds the data on to whatever is already there and restore deletes everything and then dumps it in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`pg_dump`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-pgdump.html) is the basic official tool of the project to create backups of PostgreSQL databases (or selected objects in it) in the file system.

To restore, you can either use [`pg_restore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-pgrestore.html) or simply `psql`, depending on the format of the backup.

The "Backup" and "Restore" options of [pgAdmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/) are just fronts to the above mentioned tools.

There is no (official) tool "backup" or "restore" like you seem to be implying. You are probably confusing terms.

Comment: I would just add that there are other official tools which do other kinds of backups in PostgreSQL 9+.  pg_basebackup is a good example.